# Maximize sum of all scores in tournament game

Tags: algorithmic-game-theory

There are $2^{n}$ teams. There is only one person in each team at first. Every teams' score is $0$ at first. They play a tournament game.
If team $A$ and team $B$ fights, team that has more team members wins. (If number of team members are equal, any team can win.) Number of members in losing team is the score that winner team earns.

Also, loser team writes their final score at the board, and every member of loser team becomes member of winner team. When all the tournament game ended, final winner team also writes their final score at the board. Say the sum of all numbers in the board is $M$. I want to figure out the maximum value of $M$. If the tournament tree is full binary tree, $M=n \cdot 2^{n-1}$. I also know that this problem can be interpreted into "Finding the worst case time complexity of linked list representation of disjoint sets" so $O(n \cdot 2^{n})$. I think $M=n \cdot 2^{n-1}$ is the maximum value, but I have trouble proving it. Can someone help?

Comment: Generalizing to the situation where there are $k$ teams initially: clearly the minimum possible total score is $k-1$. Computations suggest that the maximum possible total score is given by [Sequence A000788 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000788), which in particular implies your conjecture, and also suggest that every possible total score between the minimum and maximum is achievable. It seems that the maximal outcome occurs when games are always between teams of equal size (as much as possible, at least, if $k\ne 2^n$). Maybe some of these observations might help lead to a proof.

Comment: If I got your comment right, the sequence A000788 in the OEIS is just a computation for some k's but not a proof of my conjecture. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any particular time, let $S$ be the total score of all teams - either the now-constant score of losing teams, or the still changing score of winning teams. And let $L$ be the sum of the losses each player (not team) has racked up. At the start of the tournament, both values are $0$.

If a team with current score $S_1$ defeats another team with $m$ members and s current score of $S_2$, then $S_2$ remains unchanged while $S_1$ increases by $m$. So the total score $S$ increases by $m$. But the $m$ members of the losing team each add $1$ to their loss total. So the total number of losses also goes up by $m$. Thus at all times $S = L$.

Notice that in this tournament, every pair of players $a$ and $b$ are on opposing teams exactly once. Each such pairing involves one loss, but those losses are not unique. If player $b$ loses a match, that loss counts but once, while it settles all pairings between $b$ and members of the winning team. So to maximize the total number of losses, we need to minimize the number of pairings that are removed by a game - that is, the size of the winning team. Since the winning team has to be at least as big as the losing team, the number of losses is maximized when all competitions are between teams as close as possible to the same size.

When the total number of players is a power of $2$, it is possible to assure that all matches are between teams of the same size, thus maximizing losses, and total score. As you've calculated, this is $n2^{n-1}$

Comment: You said "to maximize the total number of losses, we need to minimize the number of pairings that are removed by a game", so "the number of losses is maximized when all competitions are between teams as close as possible to the same size.". I understand this intuitively, but I want a formal proof.

Comment: Have you tried yourself? I admit this is where I did the most handwaving. But this is your problem, not mine. I just gave an outline of my thoughts on the matter. That said, by the end of the tournament each pairing of opposing players will have occurred, racking up losses when it does. For any one game where the winning team has $a$ members and the losing team has $b$ members, then the loss total goes up by $b$, spread over the $ab$ pairings that were settled by it. That is, each settled pairing contributes $\frac 1a$ to the total score. The smaller $a$ is, the higher that contribution.

Comment: If there is only one game, you would be correct. But his is tournament so there will be $2^n-1$ games. For each game, say numbers of members who won are $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_{2^n-1}$, and numbers of members who lost are $b_1, b_2, \cdots b_{2^n-1}$.  If $a_1$ changes, $a_2, \cdots  a_{2^n-1}, b_1, b_2, \cdots b_{2^n-1}$ also change, and there are many restrictions other than $\Sigma a_ib_i = constant $. I appreciated your insight and tried to make a formal proof using your idea, but I think this problem is more complicated than your explanation.

Comment: Yes, choosing your teams to be equally matched vs lop-sided does affect later games. But how much thought have you put into *what* those affects are? Because every single one of those affects seems to be to *increase* the total score.